# MySQL Connection Close is not Closing the connection .NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection

Hi and thanks for reading.

My English is poor, so i hope that you understand me.

I have an MySQL Connection, that open and close the connection, that let me read, write, delete and all the SQL statements, but the problem is when i close the connection, it seems that is closing the connection, but in MySQL keeps the connection open.

There is the code.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Shared MySQLConexion As MySqlConnection
    Public Shared Function Conectar_Desconectar(ByVal Switch) As Boolean
        Conectar_Desconectar = 0
        If Switch = 1 Then
            MySQLConexion = New MySqlConnection("server=MyServer; user id=MyUser; password=MyPass;database='MyBd'")
            Try
                MySQLConexion.Open()
                Conectar_Desconectar = 1
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Else
            Try
                        MySQLConexion.Close()
                        MySQLConexion = Nothing
                        Conectar_Desconectar = 1
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Exit Function
            End Try
        End If
        Exit Function
    End Function
```

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Not your answer but an advice, the only thing that you could keep global for the lifetime of your application is the connection string. (And perhaps also this is not a good idea) The MySqlConnection should never be a Global Shared Variable. Open it when needed, use it and then close and dispose.

Comment: About your code, do not catch an exception and then do nothing with it. At least display the value of the Exception.Message. In this way you will know when there is an error.

Comment: @Steve The Exception.Message it's empty, vb.net not assume that like an error, because according to vb.net the connection was closed, but checking the connections open in MySQL, still there.

Comment: @Steve I will change that part of the code that you tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is connection pooling, which many ADO.NET providers implement. Your `MySqlConnection` is actually a fairly lightweight object and the database connection itself exists at a lower level. When you create a new `MySqlConnection`, the provider checks whether there is already a pool for that connection string and uses it if there is, otherwise creates a new pool.

There is only one pool per connection string.  When you close your `MySqlConnection` object, the underlying database connection for the pool remains open for a while, to make it faster to connect if another connection is opened.  If no new connection is made for some time, the provider closes the underlying database connection.  This is why it is advised to open and close ADO.NET connections on demand: they are optimised for just that.